# Laravel 4 - URI Parameters in Implicit Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, parameters, controller, routes

How to get URI parameters in methods inside a implicit controller?

First, I define a base route:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Then,

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    public function postProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    public function anyLogin()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

If I want to pass aditional parameters in URI, like `http://myapp/users/{param1}/{param2}` , how can I read `param1` and `param2` inside the respectve method? In this example, getIndex()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have URL like `http://myapp/users/{param1}/{param2}`
 you need to have in your controller like this:

```
Route::get('users/{param1}/{param2}', 'UserController@getIndex');
```

and access it:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($param1, $param2)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

but hey, you can also do something like this, the routes will be same:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $param1 = Input::get('param1');
        $param2 = Input::get('param2');

    }

}
```

but your URL would be something like: `http://myapp/users?param1=value&param2=value`

Comment: Probably this is the only way. I would like to benefit from the Implicit Controllers in this case too, but it seems that we can't do this. If no one else provide a better solution, you get the ponts. :)

Comment: hmm, many people says implicit controllers are hard to read and guess for your project's new developers(in case you'll have a new one). most people(including my idol jeffrey way) suggest using resource controller or just the normal way of adding controllers(ex Route::post or Route::put). but it's the developers' preference and we all have different preferences :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of creating a directory like hierarchy between models (nested routing)

Assume Album has Images, we would like an album controller (to retrieve album data) and an image controller (to retrieve image data).

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'album/{album_id}'), function()
{
    // urls can look like /album/145/image/* where * is implicit in image controller.
    Route::controller('image', 'ImageController');

});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // urls can look like /album/* where * is implicit in album controller.
    Route::controller('album', 'AlbumController');

});
```